# How to hide content on the second button click

Tags: greasemonkey

I was able to create a greasemonkey script, which shows a button, and when clicked, a table appears. But, I'd like to let the table disappear then the button got clicked a second time.
Does anyone know how that would work?

That's my original code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _TEST
// @description Adds live example button, with styling.
// @include  https://www.google.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==


var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">'
                + 'Show DE MIDs</button>'
                ;
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
document.body.appendChild (zNode);

/* --- activate button */
document.getElementById ("myButton").addEventListener (
    "click", ButtonClickAction, false
);



function ButtonClickAction (zEvent) {
    /*--- add text when clicked */
    var zNode       = document.createElement ('p');
    zNode.innerHTML =  `
    <div id="gmSomeID">
<p> IDs added by Greasemonkey</p>
        <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DE</td>
    <td>123456</td>
 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>XXXXXX</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table> 
    </div>
`;
    document.getElementById ("myContainer").appendChild (zNode);
}

//--- Style our newly added elements using CSS.
GM_addStyle ( `
    #myContainer {
        position:               absolute;
        top:                    0;
        left:                   10;
        font-size:              200px;
        background:             orange;
        border:                 3px outset black;
        margin:                 5px;
        opacity:                0.9;
        z-index:                1100;
        padding:                5px 20px;
    }
    #myButton {
        cursor:                 pointer;
    }
    #myContainer p {
        color:                  red;
        background:             white;
    }
` );
```

My attempt was this, with HideRanks, but this does not change anything.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _TEST
// @description Adds live example button, with styling.
// @include  https://www.google.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==


var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">'
                + 'Show DE MIDs</button>'
                ;
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
document.body.appendChild (zNode);

/* --- activate button */
document.getElementById ("myButton").addEventListener (
    "click", ButtonClickAction, false
);


function HideRanks (zEvent) {
    document.getElementById("UserList").classList.toggle('ButtonClickAction');
}
function ButtonClickAction (zEvent) {
    /*--- add text when clicked */
    var zNode       = document.createElement ('p');
    zNode.innerHTML =  `
    <div id="gmSomeID" onclick="HideRanks()">
<p> IDs added by Greasemonkey</p>
        <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DE</td>
    <td>123456</td>
 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>XXXXXX</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table> 
    </div>
`;
    document.getElementById ("myContainer").appendChild (zNode);
}

//--- Style our newly added elements using CSS.
GM_addStyle ( `
    #myContainer {
        position:               absolute;
        top:                    0;
        left:                   10;
        font-size:              200px;
        background:             orange;
        border:                 3px outset black;
        margin:                 5px;
        opacity:                0.9;
        z-index:                1100;
        padding:                5px 20px;
    }
    #myButton {
        cursor:                 pointer;
    }
    #myContainer p {
        color:                  red;
        background:             white;
    }
` );
```

Comment: Each time the button is clicked, test if i) text has been added ii) content has been hidden and run code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code that you can work on to suit your needs.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          _TEST
// @description   Adds live example button, with styling.
// @include       https://www.google.com/*
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

// style rules 
const css = 
`#myContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  background: orange;
  border: 3px outset black;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 1100;
  padding: 1em;
}

#myContainer button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#tableDiv {
  background: white;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  min-width: 12em;
  display: none;
}

#tableDiv.on {
  display: block;
}

#tableDiv caption {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#tableDiv th {
 text-align: left;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);


// DOM methods are many times more efficient than innerHTML
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'myContainer';
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'Show DE MIDs';
div.appendChild(button);
document.body.appendChild(div);

// create the table
const tableDiv = document.createElement('div');
tableDiv.id = 'tableDiv';
tableDiv.innerHTML = 
`<table>
  <caption>IDs added by Greasemonkey</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>DE</td>
    <td>123456</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>XXXXXX</td>
  </tr>
</table>`;
// append but it is hidden
div.appendChild(tableDiv);

// no need to get the button again
button.addEventListener('click', onClick);
function onClick() {
  // toggle on/off with each click
  tableDiv.classList.toggle('on');
}
```